# How to delete a row in a table using JSP. Error: NumberFormatException: null. -> Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, servlets, hsqldb, server-side, dao

I'm using a HSQLDB, trying to get CRUD operations to function on a table.
Having trouble with the delete function.
I'm not sure if I'm passing in the value for 'carId' correctly.

Edit: Now when I hit the delete link, a blank page is displayed with no errors showing.

> index.jsp

```
<td>
      <c:if test="${sessionScope.user != null}">
      <a name="${car.id}"  href="DeleteCarServlet?carId=${car.id}"> Delete </a>
      </c:if>
</td>
```

> CarDAO

```
public Car deleteCar(int id) {

    Connection connection = Utils.getConnection();
    Car car = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement psmt = connection
                .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM CAR WHERE ID = ?");
        psmt.setInt(1, id);
        psmt.executeUpdate();
        //list();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return car;
}
```

> DeleteCarServlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int carId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("carId"));
    Car car = CarDAO.instance.getById(carId);
    CarDAO.instance.deleteCar(carId);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a name="${car.id}"  href="DeleteCarServlet?carId=${car.id}"> Delete </a>`.

anchor tags make a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

your request is ending up in `doGet()`

Comment: Yes, thank you!
<td><c:if test="${sessionScope.user != null}"><button onClick="DeleteCarServlet?carId=${car.id}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>
</c:if></td>

Now I receive an unexpected token error but am on the right track. https://imgur.com/a/ywOoW

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on from the answer above. Rather than using an anchor tag; I used a button or input of type="submit" to solve the issue.

```
<td>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DeleteCarServlet?carId=${car.id}" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="deleteBtn">Delete</button>
    </form>
</td>
```